# Could not access directory and subdirectory using cordova File API

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am currently being challenged by an issue with the File API. I cannot seem to access the contents of a directory. The code below is supposed to access a directory and its subdirectory then read all the files inside of it.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function(filesystem) {
        var tmpPath = filesystem.root.toURL() + "Inmark/InmarkCatalog";

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(tmpPath, function(gotDir) {
            var reader = filesystem.root.createReader();
            reader.path = gotDir.toURL();
            reader.readEntries(successCatalog, failCatalogList);

        }, catalogfilefail)
    }, catalogfilefail);
```

But what is happening is that it's not going inside the directory instead it is going to the root of the internal storage. It is still running the `reader.readEntries()` function but it is passing the folders in the root directory and not the ones in the `Inmark/InmarkCatalog`.

*I recently upgraded to cordova 3.5.1 and using filesystem plugin 1.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(tmpPath, function(gotDir) {

    var reader = gotDir.createReader(); //<-- this is the answer

    reader.readEntries(successCatalog, failCatalogList);
}, catalogfilefail)
```

- I switched from using `filesystem.root.createReader()` to `gotDir.createReader()`
- my original code works only on cordova 2.9.0 and when I switched to 3.5.1, it stopped working so I had to use this new way.